# Как правильно реализовать Lazy-loading для <picture />

Tags: html, lazyloading

Использую тэг `<picture />` для реализации fallback-механизма для WebP-изображений:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="//pics.avs.io/210/50/SU@2x.webp" type="image/webp" />
    <img src="//pics.avs.io/210/50/SU@2x.png" alt="Aeroflot" title="Aeroflot" />
</picture>
```

Браузер в первую очередь пытается загрузить то, что находится в `<source />` и если встречает неподдерживаемый формат **image/webp**, то загружает то, что находится в атрибуте `src` тэга `<img />`

Теперь я хочу сделать Lazyload таких изображений с помощью [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Когда я заменяю атрибут `src` на `data-src` в тэге `<img />` то загружается изображение из тэга `<source />`. Как мне правильно реализовать Lazyload изображений не сломав при этом разметку? Хочу, чтобы это работало правильно и не вызывало вопросов у HTML-валидаторов (страница должна проходить тесты на [The W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/))